# Export Azure Subscriptions and owners (need PowerShell script)

Tags: azure, powershell, cloud, devops

I need help to create a script.

The task is to in Azure to export Subscriptions and owners of these subscriptions to CSV file. I assume I will be using powershell for this task

Please help!

Comment: @pantch12345- Could you help here in more details like what you have tried and where you got stuck so that would be helpful for the community members to check and provide you any suggestions

Comment: @VenkateshDodda-MSFT  So I have tried to select all the subscriptions that I got in my tenant by running <get-AzSubscription>in PS but I am not sure how to link it, too see subscription and owner foreach subscription.

Comment: @Pantch12345 - As in owner, do you mean all principals that have the Azure RBAC owner role assigned on subscription level?

Comment: @Pantch12345 Next time onwards  i would encourage you to follow the SO [best practices](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)and more clear information about what you are looking for as well.

Comment: @holger no as owner I mean "Classic administrator".

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below PowerShell script to pull the list of users which has the owner access to the subscription.

```html
Connect-AzAccount

$sublist= Get-AzSubscription 
foreach ($item in $sublist){

    $scopeappend= "/subscriptions/"+$item.Id
$export=(Get-AzRoleAssignment -RoleDefinitionId "8e3af657-a8ff-443c-a75c-2fe8c4bcb635" -Scope $tdt  | where {($_.ObjectType -EQ "user") -and ($_.Scope -EQ $scopeappend) }  ) | select DisplayName,SignInName
}

$export|Export-Csv -Path C:\test.csv
```

I have tested the above PowerShell script and it is working fine for me.

You can refer to [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_foreach?view=powershell-7.2) for `For-each` loop syntax as well.

Comment: Thanks for that, this is good.
But what about if I am trying to pull list of users for multiple subscriptions not just one? Thanks

Comment: In the above script `get-azsubscription` cmdlet will give you list of all the subscription and i am passing the each subscription using the for each loop and passing those subscriptions one by one and pulling the owner list

Answer (score 0):

I figure out the solution. Please see below.

```
$subs = Get-AzSubscription
$filename = "Subs_CoAdmins"+(Get-Date -UFormat "%Y-%m-%d_%H-%m-%S")+".xlsx"
$allRBACs = @()
foreach ($sub in $subs) {
    if (Select-AzSubscription -SubscriptionName $sub.Name) {
        if ($rbacs = Get-AzRoleAssignment -IncludeClassicAdministrators) {
            foreach ($rbac in $rbacs) {
                if (($rbac.Scope -like "/subscriptions/*") -and ($rbac.ObjectType -eq "Microsoft.Authorization/classicAdministrators") -and ($sub.SubscriptionPolicies.QuotaId -like "*MSDN*")) {
                    $rbacObj = New-Object -TypeName psobject
                    $rbacObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Subscription -Value $sub.Name
                    $rbacObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name SubscriptionId -Value $sub.Id
                    $rbacObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Scope -Value $rbac.Scope
                    $rbacObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name RoleDefinitionName -Value $rbac.RoleDefinitionName
                    $rbacObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name RoleDefinitionId -Value $rbac.RoleDefinitionId
                    $rbacObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name DisplayName -Value $rbac.DisplayName
                    $rbacObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name SignInName -Value $rbac.SignInName
                    $rbacObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name ObjectType -Value $rbac.ObjectType
                    $rbacObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name SubQuotaId -Value $sub.SubscriptionPolicies.QuotaId
                    $allRBACs += $rbacObj
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
$allRBACs | Export-Excel ./$filename -AutoSize -AutoFilter
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).